# SoftLayer restoreFromSnapshot API call is broken for Endurance Volumes

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can confirm that the [restoreFromSnapshot](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/restoreFromSnapshot) API call is indeed broken. I have left confidential information blank. Additionally, I want to note that I have followed correct procedure and unmounted the Endurance volume on my provisioned machine prior to issuing the restore.

```
/home/scripts > ./snapshot.py list 12193217
VOLUM ID: 12193217
+---+-------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| # |      username     |    id    | nasType  |         createDate        |
+---+-------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| 7 |       ***         | 13020991 | SNAPSHOT |  ***                      |


 /home/scripts > ./snapshot.py restore 12193217 13020991
 iscsi id: 12193217
 iscsi snapshot ID: 13020991
 True


    def restore_from_snapshot(sl_config, volume_id, snapshot_id):
        """ Restore drive from specified snapshot """
        if snapshot_id and volume_id: 
            volume_id = volume_id[0]
            snapshot_id = snapshot_id[0]
            #print "snapshot_id = %s :: volume_id = %s" % snapshot_id % volume_id
            iscsi_mgr = SoftLayer.ISCSIManager(SL.instance(sl_config).client)
            iscsi_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, volume_id,'iSCSI')
            print "iscsi id: %i" % iscsi_id
            iscsi_snapshot_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, snapshot_id,'Snapshot')
            print "iscsi snapshot ID: %i " % iscsi_snapshot_id
            iscsi = SL.instance(sl_config).client['Network_Storage_Iscsi']
            snapshot_output = iscsi.restoreFromSnapshot(iscsi_snapshot_id, id=iscsi_id)

            print snapshot_output
```

After this Nothing happens. Only through the Web API does the restore work. SLCLI is also broken(it uses this same service).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue at the moment to use the service in [ISCSIManager](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/iscsi.py). I have opened an issue about it:

- [ISCSIManager.restore_from_snapshot doesn't work as
  expected](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/750)

Probably it takes some time to be fixed. meanwhile I can provide a Python script to restore storage from snapshot:

```
"""
This script restores the volume from a snapshot that was previously taken.

See below references for more details.
Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/restoreFromSnapshot

@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer username and apiKey
user = 'set me'
api = 'set me'

# Connect to SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=user, api_key=api)

# Define the storage Id
storageId = 5805966

# Define the snapshot Id
snapshotId = 13431999

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].restoreFromSnapshot(snapshotId, id=storageId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print('Error: faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

**References**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::restoreFromSnapshot](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/restoreFromSnapshot)